# Objective C - Mac OS X - NSOpenPanel Won't Select Anything

Tags: objective-c, macos, file, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I'm new to Cocoa programming, so, overlook the fact that this may be too obvious.

I want the user to select a file with a new extension ".red".
But NSOpenPanel doesn't seem to want the same thing. It won't let me select files or folders.
Neither.
None.
This is my code:

```
    NSOpenPanel *openFile = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    NSArray *allowTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"red", @"RED", nil];

    [openFile setAllowsOtherFileTypes:true];
    [openFile setAllowsMultipleSelection:false];
    [openFile setCanChooseDirectories:false];
    [openFile setCanChooseFiles:true];
    [openFile setAllowedFileTypes:allowTypes];

    if ([openFile runModal] == NSOKButton) {

    }
```

But when I run it, it doesn't select anything...
Help?

**UPDATE:**
This is a photo of what the code above produces:
[image: Result Of Code Above]

I want to be able to select ONLY the "Untitled.red" or "RIDE Test.red" files.

ALSO! I have an exported UTI type for it in Project Settings under "Exported UTI Types" AND I also have it in Document Types.

Comment: And `red` is a registered UTI type?

Comment: umm, i added a file type for .red in project settings under document types AND exported UTI types.

Answer (score 0):

Wow! How easy fixing the problem was, was ASTONISHING! I forgot to connect the function to the menu item in the interface builder!